# Environment equivalent of \ensuremath

Tags: math-mode, environments

Is there an environment that provides a functionality similar to `\ensuremath{}` (except that I am actually interested in inserting `\[ … \]` instead of `\( … \)`)?

Motivation: I want to define a math-like environment that the user would be able to nest. Thus I want this behavior (simplified example): the environment would create an `array` environment. If we are not in math mode already, it would enclose it in `\[ … \]`. Because `\[ … \]` cannot be nested, the first sketch of the code:

```tex
\newenvironment{myenv}{%
  \[
  \begin{array}{|l}
}{%
  \end{array}
  \]%
}
```

obviously does not work as intended. I cannot do this either:

```tex
\newenvironment{myenv}{%
  \TextOrMath{\[}{}
  \begin{array}{|l}
}{%
  \end{array}
  % Here we are in math mode anyway, so to know when to insert \],
  % we need to remember at which level of nesting we are.
}
```

So a half-solution would be counting the levels of nesting, which may work in most cases. However, it fails in the (unlikely?) case when a `myenv` is nested inside text-mode content inside a `myenv`. To accurately keep track of nesting, we should use a stack. If possible at all with pure (La)TeX, this starts exceeding my TeX skills by far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by Pieter van Oostrum’s answer, here is another working solution that should be a less terrible hack than redefining `\end<NAME OF ENV>` itself. It sets a flag to `true` if the current environment was opened from text, and `false` if it was opened from math.

All instances of the `suremath` environment use the same name for the flag (`suremath@InText`), but nesting works nonetheless because environments form groups and, in TeX, *variables are local to groups*. So when a nested environment redefines (changes the value of) a variable, it does not affect the variable of the same name in the enclosing environment.

```tex
\makeatletter

  \newif\ifsuremath@InText

  \newenvironment{suremath}{%
    \TextOrMath{%
      % if opening from text context:
      \suremath@InTexttrue%
      \[%
    }{%
      % if opening from math context:
      \suremath@InTextfalse%
    }%
  }{%
    \ifsuremath@InText%
      % if closing back to text context:
      \]%
    \else%
      % if closing back to math context:
    \fi%
  }

\makeatother
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be considered a terrible hack, but it seems to me the simplest solution:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newenvironment{suremath}
{\ifmmode \def\endsuremath{}\else\def\endsuremath{\]}\[\fi}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{suremath}
  \begin{array}{c}
    a = b x + c \\ z = u x - v
  \end{array}
\end{suremath}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{suremath}
    E = mc^2
  \end{suremath}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, so this solution supports nesting after all, because command definitions are apparently local to each environment (so that, when a nested environment redefines `\endsuremath`, it does not erase the definition of the same name used by the surrounding environment). I had forgotten that. :-) What piece of *TeX code could not be considered a terrible hack anyway?